# unreadable text in HttpRequestException message

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, exception

I make an async request to a web service. When I do task.Result, it throws a HttpRequestException. But I cant read the exception Message. Why does it go bad like this? I only have this problem if im running it from Page_Load in Asp.Net webforms. If I write this code in a separate console app, it works fine. So something about asp.net webforms is creating problems. Any ideas?

Code (Exception occurs on .Result line):

```
var task = Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    return await client.RequestAccessTokenAsync(code);
                });

            token = task.Result;
```

Exception message:

`{"\u001f�\b\0\0\0\0\0\0\0��=o� \u0010��H�\u000f'�\u0005;�\u0014Q�Q��RRE�U�#�W\u001b�|�õ���V&�}�{\0��z;*�Q;\v��,�G���6F��|\u0018\u00066<2\u0017\u001a������j��l�����\u0014�U���\u0005�!�!��ޛ3��X\t~�qc�\u001f�e��\a\u0006Jv����F�H6X~�\u001ed@�1�I�m :P�ZTq��08�i\n��\u0011\n���j�B+\tΈ\u0016j�\u0001��X38t(\t\u0013�*��\u0001�����e�_��r��\"l\u000eo@��.�5J�T@z�2��L9\u0003_.�q�#��>\b\u0013��\u0002˅���Q�\u0002��B.�\u0001\0\0"}`

Exception Stack Trace:

at Xero.NetStandard.OAuth2.Client.XeroClient.d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at [classThatCallsWebService].<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()

Comment: *"I make an async request"* - You're making an asynchronous request on a different thread while waiting synchronously on the current thread (blocking the thread). Any reason you aren't just doing `token = await client.RequestAccessTokenAsync(code);`?

Comment: And how are you viewing the exception message? In the debugger? Or did you output it with code somehow? It looks like an encoding issue.

Comment: i cant use await with asp.net web forms. the only reason i use async is because all methods in the api are async anyway. i would use blocking methods if they existed. the output is from the VS debugger in the VS UI.

Answer (score 0):

Asynchronous methods work a it differently in WebForms. We'll, they *can*. You could just mark the event methods as `async void`, but that comes with some dangers. Asynchronous methods *return* at the first `await` that acts on an incomplete `Task`. But if the method is `void`, then the rest of the method can't be awaited. Sometimes that's not a big deal, sometimes it is.

WebForms has it's own way of fully supporting asynchronous methods.

1. Use `Async="true"` in the `Page` tag for that page.
2. Use [`RegisterAsyncTask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page.registerasynctask?view=netframework-4.8) to register your `async` method.

Full documentation on that is here: [Using Asynchronous Methods in ASP.NET 4.5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/aspnet/web-forms/overview/performance-and-caching/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45)